# Select statement dependent on the join

Tags: sql-server

Need help with conditional branching. Have to do a report to get member data and addresses is one of the fields. If the address is of a certain type, the logic differs, so having issues on doing the join and its select when CASE2 line.

If the address type is neither Hospital nor Facility, the join is straightforward. If it is indeed Hospital or Facility type, have to return the latest active address of NON Hospital and Facility type.

```
Addresses Table
   ADDRESS_ID, PERSON_ID, ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2

Person Table
   PERSON_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME

select distinct
P.FirstName, P.LastName, PH.HomePhone1,
A.Address_Line1 --check below for my pseudo code
from Person as P
join Phones as PH
    on P.Person_ID = PH.Person_ID
join Addresses as A
    on P.Person_ID = A.Person_ID
    and
    (
          (A.Preferred = 'Y' and A.Type not in ('Hospital','Facility')) --CASE1
       or (A.Preferred = 'Y' and A.Type in ('Hospital','Facility')) -- CASE2
    )
```

The A.Address_Line1 in CASE2 needs to come from something like

```
Select TOP 1 ADDRESS_ID from Addresses where PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID and A.TYPE not in ('Facility','Hospital') and A.Preferred = 'Y'
```

Not sure how to reply to ADyson directly, so adding that here.
I'm missing the concept on how to get the AddressLine1 for CASE2, the code I posted is what I have so far. I'm not seeing an easy way of doing this, other than with a CTE and cursors. Not a sql guru by a longshot.

The CASE1 and CASE2 are just how I expected the solution might be, so it most probably doesn't fit my requirements, but it was all I had.

I need to know how to implement this concept in SQL to populate correctly the A.AddressLine1.

```
var addressLine1 = string.empty;
if(address.Preferred = true && address.Type not in ('Hospital','Facility'))
  addressLine1 = address.addressLine1;
if(address.Preferred = true and address.Type in ('Hospital','Facility'))
  addressLine1 = select top 1 addressLine1 from Addresses where address.Preferred = 'Y' and address.Type not in ('Hospital','Facility')
```

This above pseudo code has to somehow fall into place with the top SQL statement and the joins. Just need a pointer to the proper way on how this is accomplished in SQL.

Let me know if you need more details, thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL+DML and desired output.

Comment: Why not put the case in the select?

Comment: @manderson by the looks of it, a different row needs to be returned from A depending on the Type. A Case statement in the Select can only vary the output from the same row (unless it contains a subquery, which isn't usually very desirable).

Comment: @JackieWu you've described your requirements, but you haven't described how your current code fails to meet them. What goes wrong? What output do you get currently, compared to what you actually want? Please edit the question with some more detail.

Comment: Where i can see, one of this cancels other.

        (A.Preferred = 'Y' and A.Type not in ('Hospital','Facility')) --CASE1
                or (A.Preferred = 'Y' and A.Type in ('Hospital','Facility')) -- CASE2

Comment: @ADyson Modified the post for more detail.

Comment: @JadersonLinhares that was just to try and get my message across, probably not using the proper concept at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

This will return one non Hospital/Facility address for each person. If there is a preferred non Hospital/Facility address it will return that one first, otherwise it returns the most recently added address based on `added_date desc`.

```
select 
    P.FirstName
  , P.LastName
  , PH.HomePhone1
  , x.Address_Line1
  --, x.Type 
  --, x.Preferred  
from Person as P
join Phones as PH
    on P.Person_ID = PH.Person_ID
outer apply (
  select top 1 a.Address_Line1
    --, a.Type
    --, a.Preferred
  from Addresses as A
  where P.Person_ID = A.Person_ID
    and A.[Type] not in ('Hospital','Facility')
   order by 
        case when A.Preferred = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end asc
      , A.added_date desc
    ) as x
```

---

Comment: Thank you, this might be going in the right direction. One thing of note, person can have several addresses. At any point, we need to return only 1 address per person and that depends on what is the type of the preferred address. 

If the preferred address is Facility type, we need to return their top 1 non Facility address. If their preferred address is not Facility type, we return that preferred address as is.

Comment: @JackieWu If I'm understanding you correctly, then both queries should do that. Unless you only want a preferred address... What happens when there is only 1 address that is not Hospita/Facility and it is not a preferred address?

Comment: Did some more testing and the new version you posted doesn't work as expected. Your first post seems good, I'll be doing some more testing on that one. The latest one you edited, doesn't catch the 2 cases. It returns null when the Preferred is Facility type instead of returning a non facility type address.

Comment: @JackieWu Reverted back to the previous option where it will order by the Preferred first, but return any non facility type if there is no preferred non facility type.

Comment: We are joining on the Addresses table on the Person_ID. After that, we check what is the preferred address and its type. If that type is non facility, we return that addressline1. If the type is facility, we need to get the top 1 address of a non facility type for that member. This probably needs a CASE logic similar to your original example.

Comment: Looks good so far, anyway to get that CASE logic not on the order by? The address to get when the preferred type is facility, needs to be found by the most recent address, so will need to get the address by added_date desc from addresses. So, if facility, get the top 1 address of non facility type order by added_date desc.

Comment: @JackieWu updated with `added_date desc` in the `order by`. Facility types are removed in the `where` so having the `preferred` check in the `order by` lets us do the rest all in one query.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Tested it from home and it works great. I Appreciate your help greatly. need to read up a bit on outer apply and the principles you used to get this done. I'd have done it with cursors otherwise.